# Detect a number of specific items in the inventory

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need help for detecting a number of specific items in my inventory whether it's stack or not.

This is the command I used:

`execute if entity @a[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:apple",Count:64b}]}] run command`

But the command only detects a stack of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one step to this. First, create a dummy objective.

```
/scoreboard objectives add count dummy
```

Now run this command and your item count will be stored in the objective.

```
/execute as @a store result score @s count run clear @s apple 0
```

The amount of apples you have will be stored in the count objective. You can then do:

```
/execute if entity @a[scores={count=64}] run...
```